# Custom-Taxonomy as categories: Remove "most-used" tab?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

I created a custom-taxonomy for a custom-post-type which functions as kind of categories for this post-type.

The Metabox for my taxonomy has two tabs. One for my Categories and a second tab called "Most Used" just like the normal categories for normal posts has.

Is there a way to get rid of this "Most Used" tab?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you need to first 'de-register' the metabox WordPress automatically creates:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'myprefix_remove_meta_box');  
function myprefix_remove_meta_box(){  
   remove_meta_box('my-tax-metabox-id', 'post', 'normal');  
}
```

Where `my-tax-metabox-id` is the ID of your metabox. Then 're-register' the metabox providing your own callback function which produces in the output:

```
//Add new taxonomy meta box  
 add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myprefix_add_meta_box');  
 function myprefix_add_meta_box() {  
     add_meta_box( 'mytaxonomymetabox_id', 'My Taxonomy','myprefix_mytaxonomy_metabox','post' ,'side','core');  
 }  

  function myprefix_mytaxonomy_metabox( $post ) {  
     //This function determines what displays in your metabox
     echo 'This is my taxonomy metabox';  
  }
```

Then it is simply a matter of mimicking the 'default' hierarchal metabox markup but removing the tabs. You might find [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-radio-buttons-with-taxonomies--wp-24779) I wrote, where I do this for a slightly different purpose, helpful. In short check out: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L307

That is the function responsible for outputting hierarchal metaboxes - you'll want to change that slightly (removing the tabs, and defining the `$taxonomy` variable etc.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a simpler solution, you can just add the following CSS to the backend, for example, assuming the taxonomy in question is "eventtype":

```
/* make sure tabs and the popular div itself are not shown */
#eventtype-pop,#eventtype-tabs{
    display: none !important;
}
/* make sure the All Terms div is always shown, and remove extra spacing and styles */
#eventtype-all,#eventtype-all,#eventtype-all ul,#eventtype-all ul{
    display: block !important;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background: transparent;
    border:0;
}
```

You can add this CSS to an existing admin CSS or with a simple admin hook:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'adminCSS');

function adminCSS(){
    ?><style type='text/css'>
    /* make sure tabs and the popular div itself are not shown */
    #eventtype-pop,#eventtype-tabs{
        display: none !important;
    }
    /* make sure the All Terms div is always shown, and remove extra spacing and styles */
    #eventtype-all,#eventtype-all,#eventtype-all ul,#eventtype-all ul{
        display: block !important;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        background: transparent;
        border:0;
    }
    </style><?php
}
```

This example shows inline CSS, but you could very well add an external CSS with all the rules you need.

Comment: by adding <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         $("#eventtype-pop, #eventtype-tabs").remove();
   });
     </script> You can make sure the items are removed and not just hidden.